# Erro com Unexpected token?

Tags: node.js

Eu tenho um projeto na minha maquina que usa o node.js. Ele roda tranquilo, Mas quando fui passar ele para o meu servidor no c9.io (Linux) ele esta dando esse erro:

```
user:~/workspace/guidebot (master) $ node index.js

/home/ubuntu/workspace/guidebot/index.js:44
  const init = async() => {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
```

Sendo que no arquivo index na linha 44 esta:

```
const init = async() => {        //Linha 44

  // Here we load **commands** into memory, as a collection, so they're accessible
  // here and everywhere else.
  const cmdFiles = await readdir("./commands/");
  client.logger.log(`Loading a total of ${cmdFiles.length} commands.`);
  cmdFiles.forEach(f => {
    if (!f.endsWith(".js")) return;
    const response = client.loadCommand(f);
    if (response) console.log(response);
  });
```

A versão do node que eu to usando no pc é v8.9.4, e na do servidor é: v6.11.2
Sera que o problema é esse?? Como eu faço pra atualizar o node do servidor?

Comment: Ah, vc está usando async/await, não tinha reparado (excluí minha resposta).

Comment: Sim, bem provável que o problema seja a versão do node.

Comment: Vc sabe como eu poderia atualizar ele??

Comment: Vai depender do sistema operacional, das suas permissões. Não sei dizer o passo a passo. Dá uma olhada [aqui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version) (em inglês).

Comment: Eu acabei descobrindo que seu eu dou um `node -v` ele me devolve o v6.11.2, agora se eu dou um `nodejs -v` ele me da v8.9.4!

Mas se eu tento iniciar com `node index.js` ele da aquele erro, e se eu tento inidicar com o `nodejs index.js` ele da um erro diferente...

Ja nao sei mais o que fazer '-'